# MiKTeX failing when knitting rmarkdown document

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, miktex

When I try to knot a rmarkdown word document I get the following error.

```
Sorry, but C:\Users\A12345\AppData\Local\Programs\MIKTEX~1.9\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe did not succeed.
```

This is a old version and location which is not used. I tried changing to the new by running the following after opening RStudio

```
Sys.setenv(PATH = paste(Sys.getenv("PATH"), "C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64", sep=.Platform$path.sep))
```

I also tried putting above statement in the beginning of the rmarkdown document, still getting the same error.

How can I actually change the Miktex location?

Comment: Try reinstalling `rmarkdown, knitr` and `MIKTEX`(delete all old versions). Not saying that it is guaranteed to work but did have issues with `pandoc` last night that I only solved by restarting RStudio after spending too much time figuring out what the problem was.

Comment: @NelsonGon I did just that and it worked for me! Thanks.